# Obter valores JSON usando Shell script

Tags: json, shell-script

Preciso listar os valores do campos numero e url usando shell script do json abaixo:

```
[{
   "numero": "001",
   "local": "brasil",
   "url": "http://brasil.com.br",
   "ipv4": "10.10.0.1"
}]
```

Estou usando isto aqui:
`curl -s 'http://brasil.br/pub/retorno.json' | grep -Po '(?<="url": ")[^"]*'`,

mas me retorna apenas a URL e precisaria de: numero `- url`

Comment: Já olhou essa ferramenta: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas com o `grep` não vai conseguir a string no formato que precisa (`numero - url`). Com o auxílio da ferramenta `awk` fica mais fácil:

```
curl -s 'http://brasil.br/pub/retorno.json' | grep -Po '"(numero|url)": "\K[^"]*' | awk 'NR%2{ printf "%s - ", $0; next;}1'
```

Devido a algumas limitações do lookbehind, como aceitar apenas expressões de tamanho fixo, fiz uma pequena modificação na expressão regular. O `\K` serve como uma boa alternativa para o lookbehind, pois ele é mais flexível e ainda permite que ignoremos tudo o que estiver antes dele, uma vez que ele faz com que apenas o que estiver após ele seja considerado no resultado da expressão.

O `awk` é uma ferramenta muito útil para filtrar textos. Estamos utilizando o `awk` para a cada duas linhas, elas sejam imprimidas no formato `linha_atual - linha_seguinte`.

- [Mais sobe o awk](https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Awk-Uma-poderosa-ferramenta-de-analise)
- [Mais sobre `\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente !!

Answer (score -1):

Usando o jq

O arquivo começa com um colchete de abertura ([), então o objeto inteiro é um array. Os objetos na matriz são coleções de pares chave: valor e há um objeto aninhado chamado geolocation. O geolocationobjeto contém mais pares chave: valor e uma matriz chamada coordinates.

https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Post 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Post 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Post 3"
  }
]
```

Sendo assim:

```
$ curl https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts | jq -c ". [-10:] |. [0] | .title"
```

Retorna: "Post 1"

```
$ curl https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts | jq -c ". [-10:] |. [2] | .title"
```

Retorna: "Post 3"